# Change dynamically value of flipswitch jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

i would like to change the value of a flipswitch dynamically but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="header-connection-icon">
  <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" 
     data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip1">
</div>
<div>
  <button id="test">change value</button>
</div>

$('#test').on('click', function () {
   $('#flip1').val('on');
   $('#flip1').flipswitch("refresh")
});
```

I created a jsfiddle:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/poLy86of/4/)

I'm using the latest jquery mobile and jquery plugins.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your input is a checkbox, so you need to 'Check' it :)

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
    $('#flip1').attr('checked','checked');
    $('#flip1').flipswitch( "refresh" )
  });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/poLy86of/5/)

Comment: you're my hero! Thanks!

Comment: This only seems to work once for me.  If I set it back to "off," then click again, it doesn't flip.